# Solutions for a Dynamic Infinite Tree Structure in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, nested

I am trying to build a Tree Structure, starting at a point 1, which can branch into infinte directions. Every point can path into infinite other points ( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... ) and each of those points can also path into infinite points (1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, ...).

My plan was to store an Object at every point and be able to refer to them by a position 1.1.1 etc. Also i decided to generate every point dynamically, so the Tree starts at 1 and only branches when an Object is created.

Since i tend to overcomplicate things i used a nested Dictionary, so i could refer to a object by using dict[1][1]["data"], but i'm struggling with the use of an infinite nested Dictionary:

How do i use a Dictionary if the amount of "[1]" varies? (think `dict[1][1][1]....[1]["data"]`).

I can simply loop through the dict to find the data, like

```
for i in [1.1.1]:
    point = dict[i]
```

But i can't find a way to open new dictionary branches, or store data, when the amount of "[1]" is unknown.

Basically, I want to know if a simpler solution exists and how to deal with too many nested "[]" brackets.

Comment: Your question is on how to construct this nested dict or on retrive value from it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want a different way of retrieving values than using `[]`, since as you said it's hard to do when you don't know how deep something is.

Instead you can use a simple recursive function, and use a list for your key instead of a string:

```py
def fetch_field(subtree, key_list):
    if not key_list:
        return subtree["data"]

    return fetch_field(subtree[key_list[0]], key_list[1:])

key = "1.2.1.3"
# Instead of using a string, split it into a list:
key = key.split(".")
fetch_field(tree, key)
```

You can tweak the function to accept a string instead of an array if you like, I personally prefer working with a list instead of messing around with strings.